# Connect Android mobile app to cloud database (Amazon RDS)

Tags: android, web-services, cloud, database-connection

I have an Android application and I want to move my local database in the cloud. I decided for a SQL database and not for a NoSQL, because I want to execute complex queries. I created a database instance in RDS from Amazon and I populated the database.

Now I want to connect my mobile app to my cloud database. I saw samples for NoSQL database connection, but I wasn't able to find examples for RDS. I saw that it is recommended to create a web service and connect to that web service, but it seems much more complicated than using a NoSQL and this doesn't feel right.

Does Amazon offer some API/service for Android - RDS connection? Do you know any sample code that handles this aspect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does Amazon offer some API/service for Android - RDS connection?

No. AWS does not currently have an API for interacting with an RDS instance.

> Do you know any sample code that handles this aspect?

You may want to access your database with PHP and get a JSON response. If your RDS instance is using MySQL then you’re in luck. There is already a lot of documentation on connecting Android to MySQL using PHP. You can get great sample code and instructions on [this blog post](http://itweb-projects.com/wordpress/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php).
Here is a very popular reference for [connecting Android and MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/).

Comment: can we integrate it by JDBC connection from Android...?